# Remove Radicals from an equation

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

Is there a Wolfram function to remove radicals from an equation, similar to `unrad` function in Python's`sympy`?

Like the function must give me an output equation, the solutions of which are a superset of the equation input.Example, if I have

```
e1=a^2+b^2+sqrt(a^2+b^2)==0
```

Then, I must get something like

```
(a^2+b^2)^2-(a^2+b^2)==0
```

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: `ReplaceAll[e1, Sqrt[a_] -> a]`

Comment: @eldo this is not what they wanted. They seem to basically want to square the whole e1 in order to get rid of the sqrt. I am not sure what sympy unrad does actually, but it is very long code with hundreds of lines long. So I am sure it is doing something other than just removing the radicals like this. The code for **unrad** is [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/solvers/solvers.py) starting at line 3265

Comment: `First@GroebnerBasis[{a^2 + b^2 + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]}, {a, b}]`?

Comment: @ydd - more completely, `First@GroebnerBasis[{a^2 + b^2 + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]}, {a, b}] == 0 // Simplify`

Comment: @ydd thanks!, but could you explain what the command does? Like, Groebner basis is only for a system of polynomials, so what exactly the `First@` part does?

Comment: @ydd and moreover, what to do for higher radicals. Lije, if I replace the Sqrt with CubeRoot, I get the same equation again

Comment: @vidyarthi use `First@GroebnerBasis[{a^2 + b^2 + (a^2 + b^2)^(1/3)},{a,b}]==0`. CubeRoot only gives real valued roots.

About the `First` part: I'm not actually sure. This was just from observing the first element returned is a polynomial in `a` and `b` and the second element is the original function. I would definitely test this method with a lot more expected radical functions, as it is a misuse of `GroebnerBasis`. `GroebnerBasis` is  as you pointed out only supposed to take in Polynomial system inputs. But it does output a polynomial with the same roots as the original in these cases